# Как в Python вывести список столбцом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру у меня есть список  -
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Если ввести print(list), то в консоли он выведет список так -
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

А мне нужно что бы он выдал список столбцом

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

У меня несколько списков, которые берутся из бд. print(*p, sep = "\n")
В p находится - 1, Имя, Фамилия, Отчество
Нужно сделать что бы между списками была прореха, вот так -

```
1
Имя 
Фамилия
Отчество

2
Имя
Фамилия
Отчество
```

Но сделал это одним сообщением. Как это сделать?

Comment: `print(*List, sep="\n")`

Comment: нужны запятые в строках или нет?

Comment: @MaxU спасибо! Дополнил вопрос можете посмотреть?

Comment: @Леонид, `print(*List, sep="\n", end="\n\n")` ?

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, то что нужно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
print(*List, sep="\n", end="\n\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
print(*List, sep = "\n")
```

Если запятые нужны, то так:

```
print(",\n".join(map(str, my_list)))
```

Comment: Спасибо и еще дополнительный вопрос. Если список несколько, в моем случае беру данные из БД и у меня выглядит так print(*p, sep = "\n")

Как добавить энтер между списками? Что бы

Имя
Фамилия
Отчество
энтер
Имя
Фамилия
Отчество

Comment: @Леонид добавьте в вопрос пример того что находится в `p` и ожидаемый вывод

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in my_list:
    if i != my_list[len(my_list) - 1]:
        print(f'{i},')
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Вы свой код тестировали? Посмотрите, что получится, если входным массивом дать my_list = [1, 2, 5, 4, 5 ].  Вот это -  i != my_list[len(my_list) - 1] -  мягко говоря странная конструкция при наличии enumerate().